# DataTable issue with SSRS in C#

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I have a filled DataTable and I would like to pass it to a Report in c#.
before I do this I test the DataTable in a DataGridView to make sure the data is accurate in the result I get this:(LINK TO IMAGE)

http://www.sevakabedi.com/grid.jpg

so after making sure that the data within the DataTable is correct I run this code:

```
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("dsReports", dt));
this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

The result that I get in the report is this:

http://www.sevakabedi.com/report.jpg

Here are my questions:

1. Why there is no Channel ID?
2. Why is the Call Date in long date format?

The full source code along with the Database script is available from the link below, you can download it:

http://www.sevakabedi.com/IVR_Reports.zip

Answer (score 0):

1. Look at your rdl xml. The column will show only if you have the column in there...
2. The date format - you can specify in the rdl xml file...

Comment: where is this rdl.xml file? I only have 1 rdlc file

Comment: the ChannelID exists in my rdlc

Answer (score 0):

the call date is fixed. I changed the textbox format to "d" in rdlc.
And the name of the datatable field in the DATASET was wrong, I changed it too the exact name in the query and it worked.